# Recyclerview layout changes

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

My recycler view is loaded **initially** like this:
[image: Initial Screen]
When I **turn off** and turn on the screen, the layout changes to
[image: Final Screen]

The layout file is :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_10dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_6dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mon_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tue_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/week_name1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/monday_short"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/date1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:text="sxsx"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/is_demo1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/week_name1" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/is_demo1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/demo_f23f7b_8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/tue_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/wed_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mon_layout">

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/week_name2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tues_short"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/date2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:text="sxsx"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/is_demo2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/week_name2" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/is_demo2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/demo_f23f7b_8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date2" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/wed_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/thu_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tue_layout">

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/week_name3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wed_short"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/date3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:text="sxsx"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/is_demo3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/week_name3" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/is_demo3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/demo_f23f7b_8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date3" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/thu_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fri_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/wed_layout">

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/week_name4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/thu_short"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/date4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:text="sxsx"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/is_demo4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/week_name4" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/is_demo4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/demo_f23f7b_8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date4" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/fri_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sat_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thu_layout">

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/week_name5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fri_short"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/date5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:text="sxsx"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/is_demo5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/week_name5" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/is_demo5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/demo_f23f7b_8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date5" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/sat_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sun_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fri_layout">

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/week_name6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sat_short"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/date6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:text="sxsx"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/is_demo6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/week_name6" />

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/is_demo6"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/demo_f23f7b_8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date6" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/sun_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sat_layout">

        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/week_name7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sun_short"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date7"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />    
        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/date7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
            android:text="sxsx"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/is_demo7"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/week_name7" />    
        <com.toppr.haygot.crm.widgets.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/is_demo7"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/demo_f23f7b_8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date7" />    
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The adapter is:

```
class CalendarAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>()  {

private var calendarList = mutableListOf<WeekWiseCalendar>()

fun setCalendarList(calendarList: MutableList<WeekWiseCalendar>) {
    val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(CalendarDiffUtil(this.calendarList, calendarList))
    this.calendarList.clear()
    this.calendarList.addAll(calendarList)
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_week_calendar, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return this.calendarList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val calendarDataList = calendarList[position].calendarList
    holder?.let {
        it.itemView.date1.text = "${calendarDataList[0].date}"
        it.itemView.is_demo1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        it.itemView.date2.text = "${calendarDataList[1].date}"
        it.itemView.is_demo2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        it.itemView.date3.text = "${calendarDataList[2].date}"
        it.itemView.is_demo3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        it.itemView.date4.text = "${calendarDataList[3].date}"
        it.itemView.is_demo4.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        it.itemView.date5.text = "${calendarDataList[4].date}"
        it.itemView.is_demo5.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        it.itemView.date6.text = "${calendarDataList[5].date}"
        it.itemView.is_demo6.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        it.itemView.date7.text = "${calendarDataList[6].date}"
        it.itemView.is_demo7.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}

class CalendarDiffUtil(val oldList: MutableList<WeekWiseCalendar>, val newList: MutableList<WeekWiseCalendar>) : DiffUtil.Callback() {


    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition].weekNum == newList[newItemPosition].weekNum && oldList[oldItemPosition].year == newList[newItemPosition].year
    }

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return true
    }

}
```

}

The constraint layout version 1.0.2. Is it because of the constraint layout which is causing the issue or something else. I want the layout for the red dot to be visible.

Comment: Just quick remark - in your onBindViewHolder method you should change 'holder?.let {' to 'holder?.apply {' and remove 'it' references from code block. Also the method refference is 'onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int)'

Comment: you can set the adapter `onResume(..)` again !!

Answer (score 0):

Few things here that might be helpful:

First: 
In your onBindViewHolder method you should change

```
holder?.let {
 it.sth = ...
```

to

```
holder?.apply {
  sth = ...
```

Second: Method referrence is

```
fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int)
```

Third:
It looks better and is more OOD when you write something like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    holder?.bind(calendarList[position].calendarList, listener)
}
```

and then in  your ViewHolder:

```
    fun bind(item: Sth) -> Unit) = with(item) {
        date1.text = "${item[0].date}"
        is_demo1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        ...
    }
```

Fourth: I would guess that your DiffUtil is bady implemented (can't say for sure - cause you didn't post your DiffUtil.Callback). I suggest checking if it works without DiffUtil. If so than i recomend this tutorial: https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00

Hope it helps somehow :)